# correlation between two variables within a third group

Tags: correlation, mixed-model

I'm testing correlation between two variables `v1` and `v2`, but they are clustered by a third variable `group`. Can I directly use the correlation test (i.e., Spearman test) without accounting the cluster? What is the possible issue? If not, what test should I conduct? Is intraclass correlation the correct test I should use? My data are not normally distributed.

I have 2 sets of data, they have 40, 80 `group`. My group is subject, and `v1` and `v2` are two continuous variables that are two different behavioural data drawn from each individual.

example data

```
group   v1   v2
 1      2    1
 1      2    0
 1      8    9
 2      7    1
 2      9    2
 2      3    1
 3      2    2
 3      1    1
 3      1    2
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many groups do you have ? What is the relation between `v1` and `v2` (if any), and what type of data are they ?

Comment: @RobertLong. I have updated my question, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More information would be useful, but in general when data are clustered, you must account for the possible non-independence of observations within clusters. This means that you cannot use simple correlation (if there is a clustering effect)

One way to analyse your data is to run a mixed effects model, with `group` as a random effect. You have plenty of groups to do this. It would be a regression model, rather than a simple correlation, but it will account for non-independence between clusters. This will tell you the *association* between the two variables (similar to a correlation coefficient), adjusting for clustering effect. However, some caveats are:

- you will need to choose an "outcome" variable. This many be obvious in your situation but there is insufficient information to determine this from the OP.
- You will need to choose an appropriate model given the distribution of your outcome variable. You say it is not normally distributed, which is OK. Mixed effects models can handle a wide range of distributions.

Comment: Thanks! So I should do a univariate regression in mixed effect model then? Such that `v1~v2|group`? The coefficient can be interpreted as similar as the correlation coefficient?

Comment: Yes, though please check [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/whats-the-difference-between-correlation-and-simple-linear-regression) for the differences between correlation and regression.

Comment: Thanks for that post! As far as I know, a univariate regression = Pearson correlation, but what if my test requires spearman correlation? Is there any way to transform into Spearman in mixed effect model?

Comment: Please ask a new question regarding that. Feel free to ping me in a comment

Comment: @ Robert Long here is my question about the Spearman and regression, thanks!